# Why won't SQL Server return 1,0 when given IN()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on SQL Zoo Select from Nobel from 14. http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial. The given answer works in MySQL:

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984
ORDER BY  subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'), subject, winner
```

However it does not work in SQL Server. SQL server seems to not recognize how to use  IN ('Physics','Chemistry'). Can anyone explain why?

This is the question:
Show the 1984 winners and subject ordered by subject and winner name; but list Chemistry and Physics last.

The answer in SQL Server, in case anyone wants it:

```
SELECT winner, subject 
FROM nobel 
WHERE yr = 1984 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN subject IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, subject, winner
```

Answer (score 1):

`subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry')` is a logical condition. It evaluates to either `true` or `false`. Boolean values have no orders: `true` is not greater or less than `false`. They are simply not equal to each other.

Many programming languages, C being the most prominent, make `false = 0` and `true = 1`, so that `false < true`. It makes no mathematical sense, but that's what the language designers decided.

It just so happen that MySQL also follows this line of convention. So:

```
subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry') = 1 for Physics and Chemistry
                                   = 0 for everything else
```

Using it in an `ORDER BY` places Physics and Chemistry last. Microsoft decided not to support this syntax in their product and you have to do it differently.

Comment: "*Boolean values have no order*" - is not true. The SQL standard **does** define an order for boolean values: Quote from the standard (Part 2, Foundation, Section 4.5.2) "*All boolean values and SQL truth values are comparable and all are assignable to a site of type boolean. The value `True` is greater than the value `False`*"

Comment: Too bad that there isn't a product that sticks to the ANSI SQL standard. Every vendor does it their way :(

Comment: Well Microsoft has a history of ignoring standards that were not established by the - but they are getting better. Postgres btw. does handle `boolean` values correctly (SQL Server doesn't even have a native `boolean` data type).

Comment: The same goes for conditional `SUM(subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'))` there you get the number of row satisfy the condition.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and was exactly what I needed to know!